# jquery selector issue for toggle

Tags: jquery

My toggle is happening but it is getting applied to second nested level as well.

On load, i only want the Parent One and Parent Two, first nested UL to not show. The second nested UL will remain open inside this LI.

When i click Parent One or Parent Two, the first nested ul should open/close. The second nested UL, should always remain open inside this LI.

```
<div class="navColumn">
    <ul class="ltColmenu">
        <li><a href="">No Child 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">No Child 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">No Child 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="headNavItem headNavItemClose">Parent One</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="headNavItem">Item 4</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Item 1 -1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item 1 -2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item 1 -3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item 1 -4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">No Child 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">No Child 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="headNavItem headNavItemClose">Parent Two</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="headNavItem">Item 8</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Item 2 -1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item 2 -2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item 2 -3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item 2 -4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have the following jquery, the selector is picking up Item 4 and Item 8 as well. I don't want this behavior. I only want the selector to pick up Parent One and Parent Two. How can i fix this issue?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //onload hide first level nested items, all other levels will remain open inside top LI
    $("ul.ltColmenu > li ul").slideToggle("fast");
    //click on first level LIs, as first level only toggles. all other levels will remain open inside top LI
    $("ul.ltColmenu > li a.headNavItem").click(function(){
        if ($(this).next("ul").is(':visible')) {
            $(this).removeClass("headNavItemOpen").removeClass("headNavItemClose").addClass("headNavItemClose");
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass("headNavItemOpen").removeClass("headNavItemClose").addClass("headNavItemOpen");
        }
        $(this).next("ul").slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //onload hide first level nested items, all other levels will remain open inside top LI
    $("ul.ltColmenu > li > ul").slideToggle("fast");
    //click on first level LIs, as first level only toggles. all other levels will remain open inside top LI
    $("ul.ltColmenu > li > a.headNavItem").click(function(){
        if ($(this).next("ul").is(':visible')) {
            $(this).removeClass("headNavItemOpen").removeClass("headNavItemClose").addClass("headNavItemClose");
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass("headNavItemOpen").removeClass("headNavItemClose").addClass("headNavItemOpen");
        }
        $(this).next("ul").slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });

});
```